# How to get 'man gfind' when I enter 'man find'?

Tags: zsh, symlink, alias, macos, darwin

On my new-ish mac os/Darwin system, my `find` tool is an 11-year-old BSD version. I have used MacPorts to install a more current version: GNU's `find`, which MacPorts has named `gfind`, and placed in `/opt/local/bin/`. The aging Apple-supplied `find` remains in `/usr/bin/find`.

I need to retain the old version of `find` in the event that it's still used by the system, but I'd much prefer to enter `find` at the command line instead of `gfind`. Old habits and all of that...

I know I can run `gfind` when entering `find` by either creating a `link` in `/opt/local/bin/` (it's before `/usr/bin` in my PATH), or by creating an `alias` in `.zshrc`. Both of these work fine. My problem is how to get `man gfind` when I enter `man find` - I've tried several versions of `alias` in `.zshrc`, but none have worked.

How do I get this to work?  How do I get `man gfind` in my pager display when I enter `man find` at the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple and general way to put all of the GNU (*'g-prefixed'*) tools installed by MacPorts, **and** their associated manuals, on `$PATH` in front of the native tools:

###### ➤ The MacPorts package manager creates (& updates) a directory that contains symlinks to *all* of the GNU tools & manuals installed on MacOS; i.e. the *"g-prefixed"* tools:

```
/opt/local/libexec/gnubin
```

There are two (or more) sub-directories that contain the manuals. All of the files in these directories are *symlinks* to the GNU tools & manuals. For example:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  20 Dec 26 17:21 find -> /opt/local/bin/gfind 

# under gnubin/man/man1 : 

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin   36 Dec 26 17:21 find.1.gz -> /opt/local/share/man/man1/gfind.1.gz
```

If we check `manpath`:

```bash
% manpath
/opt/local/share/man:/usr/local/share/man: /* etc. etc */
```

###### ➤ And so we see that if we add `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin` to $PATH, we will run `gfind` when the `find` command is entered, and we will view `man gfind` when we enter `man find`. The PATH may be modified by prepending `gnubin` to the existing PATH:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

If you're happy with this, you can add this `export` to your `~/.zprofile`. and you are done. No more re-training your fingers to type `gfind` in stead of `find`.

###### ➤ You can also *tailor* this easily:

Many of the GNU tools are packaged as a "set", meaning that `gfind` is packaged with several other tools in the [Findutils package](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) - which includes `glocate`. I was OK with this until I learned that there is a **stubborn bug** in `gupdatedb` that effectively disables it (and thereby renders `glocate` useless) - owing to some diffs between Darwin & Linux.

I use the native `locate` occasionally, and wanted to avoid wasting any further time on the GNU version. The "fix" for this is to `unlink` the symlinks to `glocate`, `gupdate` and their associated manuals from `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin`.

###### ➤ But there is one more *kink* to sort if you *"tailor"* gnubin:

I learned that MacPorts periodically ***updates*** `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin`, and have been informed by one of the maintainers that these updates will ***"repair"*** my modifications! This adds only one step to the solution: copy the original `gnubin` folders to another location; make all edits (`unlink`s) to that alternate location and use it in the PATH. Here's how to do that:

```
% sudo cp -RPp /opt/local/libexec/gnubin/ /opt/local/libexec/gnubin-m
```

*<sup>Note that this is the **native**, BSD version of `cp`</sup>*

#### ➤ The final solution - edit/unlink gnubin-m & add to PATH

```
% sudo unlink /opt/local/libexec/gnubin-m/locate
% sudo unlink /opt/local/libexec/gnubin-m/man/man1/locate.1.gz 
...
export PATH="/opt/local/libexec/gnubin-m:$PATH"
```

Comment: Note that with `zsh`, you'd rather do `path=(/new/dir $path)` or `path[1,0]=/new/dir` to insert a new dir at the start of `$PATH`.

Comment: I didn't know `zsh` had a different syntax for modifying $PATH - thanks, I'll look into that. It does work as shown though... is there an advantage of the proper syntax?

Comment: `PATH=/new/dir:$PATH` will also work, it's just that in zsh, like in (t)csh, `$PATH` is mapped to the `$path` array, and it makes more sense to manipulate it as a list.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I'm sure you're correct, but having a difficult time finding much in the `zsh` documentation. [I did find this](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html#l24), but it's not yet sunk in. Do you have other references?... I'd like to read more on the details.

Comment: See `info zsh path` or `info zsh PATH` assuming the documentation is installed in info format. You'll also find it in the man pages, though man is not adapted for a manual this big.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need original find page - just make link from `find.1.gz` to `gfind.1.gz`

Better, would be to edit MANPATH environment variable and put your own tree (man1, man2, etc) in it with a substitution of the man pages.

Comment: Did you check this on a mac? I have no MANPATH environment variable.

Comment: If you do no have it - create it. Do `man man` for better understanding.